# Why can I not make the following array?

Tags: java, arrays

```js
public class This{

public static void main(String args[])
   {

      System.out.println();     
      Deck deck = new Deck();
      System.out.println(deck);
   }
}


class Deck02 
{
   private Card[] cards;            
   private int size;

   public Deck02() 
   {
      cards = new Card[52];         
      size = 0;
   }

   public int size()
   {
      return size;
   }

   public boolean isEmpty()
   {
      return size == 0;
   }

   public void add(String suit, String
```

For some reason every compiler I plug this into highlights "private Card[] cards;" and tells me to make it into a class. I need it to be an array.

Comment: I think it's complaining that it cannot find your `Card` class.

Comment: Yes, you need it to be an array of `Card` objects, which means you have to declare a `Card` class.

Comment: **Read the error message**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler is telling you that the data type `Card` doesn't exists, therefore, you can't create a variable of this type.

You forgot to implement the `Card` class, didn't you?!